# Embedd code for a single visual in a Report using Powerbi Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a 4 page PowerBi report hosted on an internal PowerBi report server. I need to generate an embed code for each visual(or one embed code with a filter for each visual on it) to post on a website using iframes. Everything I have seen online has spoken to using an API.

Is this request possible and if so how might I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you have each visual on it's own report page, and then embed? or perhaps create separate reports for each visual?

Comment: This seems to be the most correct way of achieving what I want. Tedious yes, but correct.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't File > Embed report > Website or portal do the trick for you?

[image]

Comment: For the entire report yes, but I was hoping to generate a embed code for each visual in the report instead.